# How bad is it to *not* reboot a server after kernel updates?

Tags: linux

I’m administrating a few Debian Linux server, and install package updates when apticron notifies me of them. Occasionally I see updates to `linux-image-[something]` packages, but don’t bother to reboot the server. How bad is this in terms of vulnerability?

Answer (score 12):

You aren't running the new kernel until your reboot, so in terms of security the vulnerability you'd patch by updating the kernel **isn't patched until you reboot**.

Linux 4.0 has [support](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9138126) for no-reboot patching. It's still in very early stages and the userspace tools (systemd, etc) don't yet support it but the code is there and hopefully it'll become widely supported soon.

Another solution would be to use something like [Uptrack](https://www.ksplice.com/) that can update *some* parts of the kernel without rebooting, but that requires a subscription and is only available for some distrubutions.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you aren't rebooting, your system still runs with the old kernel. This means it is vulnerable to all vulnerabilities included in the update.

When an update for a package is released, it means any vulnerabilities fixed by that update are now known (when the project is bazaar-style, they are likely already known for quite some time while the fix went through bugtracking and QA). That means any malware authors anywhere in the world have the opportunity to create exploits and use them. Should they finish their work before you apply the patch through rebooting, they will be able to hit you. To make this time-window as small as possible you should reboot soon.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're hot swapping kernels, you're not running the newest version of the kernel.